# What is the most common equivalent name for “handal”, a very bitter fruit?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, food

What is the most common name of a very bitter fruit, a word that is the equivalent of *handal* (also spelled “handhal”)?

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citrullus_colocynthis), I found several names for this melon-like fruit: **bitter apple, bitter cucumber, desert gourd, wild gourd, egusi,** or **vine of Sodom**.

[image: a vine growing on dry dusty land, the fruit has the form and colourization similar to small watermelons]
[image: dissected fruit displaying the pulp and seeds, the seeds are similar to apple pips]

- Which is the most familiar term for native speakers?
- Why is it also called “vine of Sodom”? Is it well-known?

Comment: 'Bitter fruit' recounts in telling detail the CIA operation to overthrow the democratically elected government of Jacobo Arbenz of Guatemala in 1954.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I see, "English culture" might not be a very idiomatic term  for what could possibly be, I guess, "English husbandry", and so has to be taken as meaning the culture associated with the English civilization. Thanks for making me notice the problem.

Comment: I think I may have found it http://www.floraofqatar.com/citrullus_colocynthis.htm There are several names for this fruit: **bitter apple, bitter cucumber, desert gourd, egusi, or vine of Sodom**

Comment: https://www.healthbenefitstimes.com/facts-and-benefits-of-bitter-apple/

Comment: @LPH I have cast my vote to reopen, the fruit itself is rather unusual and fascinating. The English terms varied and perhaps none are commonly known. Maybe in the US it has a following?

Comment: If the plant grows in the Mediterranean Basin and Asia, especially Turkey, which are not native English speaking communities, why would there be a familiar English term?

Comment: I've voted to reopen as well. This is not a question about farming: the OP is asking for the English name for a particular fruit. The problem is that this fruit is not well-known to many English speakers, certainly in the UK. I have seen it in markets in Bradford, and seen it called "bitter melon", but I've never had it.

Comment: *Why is it also called “vine of Sodom”?* Obviously, it grows in the manner of a vine. Sodom is a reference that reflects the unwholesomeness of the biblical town of "Sodom" that was destroyed by God because all the inhabitants were degenerate. As the fruit tastes disgusting, it seems apt.  *Is it well-known?* No, not at all. Very few people would recognise the plant, and even fewer would be able to name it.

Comment: If you call it “bitter cucumber” even people who have never heard of it will understand its essence.

Comment: Please accept the answer that helped you most. There is a grey checkmark under the bottom arrow which will become green when you click on it. The author of the answer receives 15 reputation points and you, the OP, will get 2 reputation bonus points.

Answer (score 6):

> Why is it called vine of Sodom?

[Josephus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus) wrote of the fruit of Sodom:

> The country of Sodom borders upon it. It was of old a most happy land, both for the fruits it bore and the riches of its cities, although it be now all burnt up. It is related how, for the impiety of its inhabitants, it was burnt by lightning; in consequence of which there are still the remainders of that Divine fire, and the traces [or shadows] of the five cities are still to be seen, **as well as the ashes growing in their fruits; which fruits have a color as if they were fit to be eaten, but if you pluck them with your hands, they dissolve into smoke and ashes.**

["B. J." iv. 8, § 4](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=J.+BJ+4.8.4&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0148)

So, this supposed fruit of Sodom looked edible, but was actually inedible. In trying to identify the plant Josephus described, [some modern scholars have proposed *Citrullus colocynthis.*](https://www.biblicalcyclopedia.com/V/vine-of-sodom.html)  "Turns to smoke and ash when plucked" sounds to me like a pretty poor description of *Citrullus colocynthis*.  It does at least grow in the correct location.  And though Josephus doesn't state as much, there's some argument to be made that the plant was a vine.

The somewhat dubious argument is that Josephus's "fruit of Sodom" refers to the same plant as the "vine of Sodom" described in [Deuteronomy 32:32](https://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0532.htm):

> :כִּֽי־מִגֶּ֤פֶן סְדֹם֙ גַּפְנָ֔ם וּמִשַּׁדְמֹ֖ת עֲמֹרָ֑ה עֲנָבֵ֨מוֹ֙ עִנְּבֵי־ר֔וֹשׁ אַשְׁכְּלֹ֥ת מְרֹרֹ֖ת לָֽמוֹ
>
> For their vine is of the **vine of Sodom**, and of the fields of Gomorrah; their grapes are grapes of gall, their clusters are bitter;

The idea is that the "vine of Sodom" was a specific plant, rather than a metaphorical kind of vine that you might characterize as being sodomic. That doesn't seem obvious to me.  Nor is it obvious that, even if the "vine of Sodom" were a specific plant, the same name would have been used by the writers of Deuteronomy, who were probably writing in the 7th century BCE, and by Josephus who wrote about seven hundred years later.

But fortunately, the question was why do some people call this plant "vine of Sodom" and not whether doing so makes sense.

Comment: Josephus's description sounds like a [Puffball](https://www.google.com/search?q=puffball&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALeKk003V4tYukZp_pLT70nws8Zx24Jr2g:1596883204774&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwis9avBtYvrAhUOzzgGHf3_A28Q_AUoAXoECDQQAw&biw=2457&bih=1269) , some versions of which  can be very large. Some at least of these literally self-dismantle with a "puff" of spores when picked without great care.

Comment: I had that same thought @RussellMcMahon.  I don't know any Greek, so I have no idea whether *καρποῖς* might have been used to describe fungus.  Also, not sure that puffballs grow is Israel. But otherwise, it seems like a better guess than colocynth.

Answer (score 5):

Based purely on the descriptive terms that have now been added to the question, [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bitter%20apple%2C%20bitter%20cucumber%2C%20desert%20gourd%2C%20wild%20gourd%2C%20egusi%2C%20vine%20of%20Sodom&corpus=26&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbitter%20apple%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbitter%20cucumber%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdesert%20gourd%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwild%20gourd%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cegusi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvine%20of%20Sodom%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbitter%20apple%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbitter%20cucumber%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdesert%20gourd%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwild%20gourd%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cegusi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cvine%20of%20Sodom%3B%2Cc0) says that the most common term (at least in print) is *egusi*:

[image: Bitter apple, bitter cucumber, desert gourd, wild gourd, egusi, or vine of Sodom]

Interestingly, *egusi* is more common than even terms like *bitter apple* and *wild gourd*, which could be used in contexts that have nothing to do with the particular fruit at all.

Also note that *vine of Sodom* was the most common for a while in the 19th century.

If I add *handal* into the ngram, it ends up in second-last place, just above *desert gourd*.

Comment: Try adding *colocynth* to that ngram.  You'll see that it's a bit more common than *egusi* now, and that in the 19th century, it was far more common than any of the alternatives.

Comment: @Juhasz  Sounds [fishy](https://www.google.com/search?q=coelacanth+fish&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALeKk000op2B0PKVFuFaOQCq_t6HJ3t55Q:1596883423361&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSx8mptovrAhUzzTgGHVdJBBIQ_AUoAXoECDgQAw&biw=2457&bih=1269) to me :-). No. Wait! ...